# JavaScript click button by value from chrome console

Tags: javascript

I have the following page :

[image]

And the following code for these elements:

```
<td align='left' height='20' width='null' valign='middle' >
<input type="submit"  name="BTN_SUBMIT0"  value="No"></td>

    <td align='right' height='20' width='null' valign='middle' >
<input type="submit"  name="BTN_SUBMIT0"  value="Yes"></td>
```

How do I click a button from console using JavaScript not having its ID, but having its value ?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input[value="no"]').click()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get just get the element and use the click() method.

```js
document.querySelector("input[value='Yes']").click();
```

```html
<td align='left' height='20' width='null' valign='middle' >
<input type="submit"  name="BTN_SUBMIT0"  value="No"></td>

    <td align='right' height='20' width='null' valign='middle' >
<input type="submit"  name="BTN_SUBMIT0"  value="Yes" onclick="this.style.background='red';"></td>
```